# jqueryui resizable handle does not move with element on a non-jqueryui-resizable-resize

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

If I make an element resizable with jqueryui and I change the size of this element without using jqueryui resizable, but for example by jquery.css('width'), then the handle of the jqueryui resizable does not move with the element.

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png"/>
<input id="resizeImage" type="button" value="Resize Image" />
```

Script:

```
var image = $('#image');
image.resizable();
$('#resizeImage').on('mouseup', function () {
  image.css('width', parseInt(image.width() - 1, 10) + 'px');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mghhf/2/)

Any idea how to work-around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.resizable()`, it wraps that element in `<div class="ui-wrapper"></div>`.  I suggest doing the following:

```
var image = $('#image');
image.resizable();
$('#resizeImage').on('mouseup', function () {
     image.css('width', parseInt(image.width() - 1, 10) + 'px');
     $('.ui-wrapper').css('width', parseInt(image.width() - 1, 10) + 'px');
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Mghhf/5/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it works!
I just modified the selection of the wrapper by taking the parent of the image. Thereby it does not affect other elements with the ui-wrapper class.

Comment: Should I make a bug report about this on jqueryui?

Answer (score 1):

By destroying and reinitializing the resizable it works, but that seems overkill to me...

```
var image = $('#image');
image.resizable();
$('#resizeImage').on('mouseup', function () {
image.resizable('destroy')
  .css('width', parseInt(image.width() - 1, 10) + 'px')
  .resizable();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mghhf/3/